# Split ordered file in Linux

Tags: linux, perl, shell, sed, awk

I have a large delimited file (with pipe '|' as the delimiter) which I have managed to sort (using linux sort) according to first (numeric), second (numeric) and fourth column (string ordering since it is a timestamp value). The file is like this:

```
77|141|243848|2014-01-10 20:06:15.722|2.5|1389391203399
77|141|243849|2014-01-10 20:06:18.222|2.695|1389391203399
77|141|243850|2014-01-10 20:06:20.917|3.083|1389391203399
77|171|28563|2014-01-10 07:08:56|2.941|1389344702735
77|171|28564|2014-01-10 07:08:58.941|4.556|1389344702735
77|171|28565|2014-01-10 07:09:03.497|5.671|1389344702735
78|115|28565|2014-01-10 07:09:03.497|5.671|1389344702735
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to split this file to multiple text files with an awk, sed, grep or perl one liner whenever the first column or the second column value changes. The final result for the example file should be 3 text files like that:

```
77|141|243848|2014-01-10 20:06:15.722|2.5|1389391203399
77|141|243849|2014-01-10 20:06:18.222|2.695|1389391203399
77|141|243850|2014-01-10 20:06:20.917|3.083|1389391203399

77|171|28563|2014-01-10 07:08:56|2.941|1389344702735
77|171|28564|2014-01-10 07:08:58.941|4.556|1389344702735
77|171|28565|2014-01-10 07:09:03.497|5.671|1389344702735

78|115|28565|2014-01-10 07:09:03.497|5.671|1389344702735
```

I could do that in Java of course, but I think it would be kind of overkill, if it can be done with a script. Also, is this possible that the filenames created use those two columns values, something like 77_141.txt for the first file, 77_171.txt for the second file and 78_115.txt for the third one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` is very handy for this kind of problems. This can be an approach:

```
awk -F"|" '{print >> $1"_"$2".txt"}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"|"` sets field separator as `|`.
- `{print > something}` prints the lines into the file `something`.
- `$1"_"$2".txt"` instead of `something`, set the output file as `$1"_"$2`, being `$1` the first field based on the `|` separator. That is, `77`, `78`... And same for `$2`, being `141`, `171`...

Comment: Thanks @devnull you are right, I wanted to append so `>>` instead of `>`!

Comment: Excellent. +1 and accepted your answer. Thanks both of you for your trouble.

Comment: @BMW one is enough in many cases. But if you already have the files and want to append data, `>` will first truncate and then add content. Instead, `>>` will add data after the previous one.

Comment: What do you mean, @BMW? Cannot understand the reason.